# (wordpress)show a sentence highlighting search keywords in search result page

Tags: php, wordpress

Default search for wordpress doesn't show the keyword for all search results in the search query. For example: If search keywords belong to the second paragraph and I am displaying the limited characters of only the first paragraph, the keyword is not shown. To be more precise, here's an example.
I have a page with content the following content:

> This is merely a test. This is just an example.

and in the search page, I have called the loop

```
<?php

    while(have_posts() ): the_post();
    echo substr(get_the_content(), 0, 10);
    endwhile;
?>
```

Now when I search for the keyword "example", the post is shown in the search results but since only first 10 characters are displayed, the keyword doesn't display. I limit to 200 characters in my site, what I want is to show sentence or two with the keyword highlighted in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
while(have_posts() ): the_post();
            $str=substr(get_the_content(), 0, 10);
            $keyword=$_REQUEST['s'];
            echo preg_replace("/\w*?".preg_quote($keyword)."\w*/i", "<b>$0</b>", $str)
endwhile;
```

For highlight the word in the string

```
preg_replace("/\w*?$keyword\w*/i", "<b>$0</b>", $str)
```

`\w*?` matches any word characters before the keyword (as least as possible) and `\w*` any word characters after the keyword.

For Unicode support, use the *u* flag and `\p{L}` instead of `\w`:

```
preg_replace("/\p{L}*?".preg_quote($keyword)."\p{L}*/ui", "<b>$0</b>", $str)
```